# How can I split an excel worksheet into multi files based on a name in a column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I need to split an excel worksheet into multi files based on a name in a column. This sheet has over 4000 rows.. Example

Workbook Name: CO DILE

Sheet name: Report01

Affiliate     Account    Date        Officer Name      Amount

XXP           1          1/1/98      Kelly, Ali       $255585

XXP           2          1/1/98      Kelly, Ali       $256566

XXP           3          1/1/98      Kelly, Ali       $478751

XXP           1          1/1/98      Abot, Rachel     $255585

XXP           2          1/1/98      Abot, Rachel     $256566

XXP           3          1/1/98      Abot, Rachel     $478751

New excel workbooks:

File Name: Kelly, Ali CO DILE

Affiliate     Account    Date        Officer Name      Amount

XXP           1          1/1/98      Kelly, Ali       $255585

XXP           2          1/1/98      Kelly, Ali       $256566

XXP           3          1/1/98      Kelly, Ali       $478751

New excel workbooks:

File Name: Abot, Rachel CO DILE

XXP           1          1/1/98      Abot, Rachel     $255585

XXP           2          1/1/98      Abot, Rachel     $256566

XXP           3          1/1/98      Abot, Rachel     $478751

Please please help!!!

Comment: Sure hope you made up your data for this example.  You'll need VBA to solve your problem from within Excel, so you'll have to dive into that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going to need to export your data to text and use a scripting language to read the text and automate the creation of files. I would do this like so:

- Export your workbook to a CSV file
- Write an ASP page / VB script / Another technology that takes each line of text from you CSV file and parses it, creating new CSV files as it goes
- Copy and paste the text from the CSV file into the ASP page
- The CSV files can then be opened in Excel or maybe there's a bulk CSV to Excel conversion tool?

Hope you find this answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a prohibitively large number of files to create, you could do this manually by filtering the original data by Name and then copying the matches into a new workbook.  I would say if you have 25 or fewer files to create, this might make more sense than taking the time to wrestle with the VBA.